# Decline and the ending of Buddhism

Tags: buddha, maitreya-buddha

Here is link giving a bit of details that Buddha preached about the decline of Buddhism after parinibbana.

http://www.lawsofthenature.com/GotamaSasana.aspx

I share with you the following passage taken from the page of the above link

> The Buddha said that after His parinibbaana, only for 1,000 years will
>   the monks be able to acquire the analytical knowledge (Patisambhida),
>   or what we know as Arahanthship or deep knowledge. Then, as time goes
>   on, they will only be able to attain Anaagami (Never return). And then
>   only Sakadagami (Once return), and finally, only Sotapanna (Stream
>   enterer). With the death of the last disciple who has attained
>   Sotapanna, the attainments will disappear.

Here's my issue with the above. From what I understand is that after a certain period of time after parinibbana, the maximum attainment that one could achieve reduces from arahant to anagami and so on. But this is illogical because if a person attain anaagaami he/she will only have at most 1 life where he/she will become an arahant which makes the above statement false, unless it means that the person will be born as a deva maybe having a very long lifetime until the next Buddha. This is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Anagamis are born in one of the five [Suddhavasa Brahma realms](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html). There they will attain Arahanthship. Yes, they have a very long life span. The lowest realm 'Aviha' has a life span of 1000 Maha Kalpas. So they will see many Buddhas in the future before entering Parinibbana.

The text is talking about monks. That means the human world. Divine beings are not discussed here.

Comment: This is a question from the same link. Why is refraining from claiming to have attained the four spiritual levels a deadly sin?

Comment: @Heisenberg It's the other way round: killing, claiming attainment, stealing, and sexual conduct are all "deadly sins", in the sense that a person who commits one of those acts is no longer a bikkhu. There's more to being a bikkhu than just keeping those precepts, but the link you posted said that "as time goes on" these are the only four disciplines they will keep.

Comment: Why is claiming attainment wrong? I am sorry if this is totally unrelated. I can post this as a fresh question if you wish

Comment: Claiming that you are enlightened(4 stages), when you are not, invalidates your monkhood, if  done knowingly. Truly enlightened beings do not usually discuss their attainment with others.

Comment: @Heisenberg [This commentary](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#robbery) classifies it as robbery or false pretenses. Technically it's *falsely* claiming attainments that's wrong (but monks avoid making claims at all). See also page 87 [of this](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf) which says, "All conscious lies are forbidden by the first p›cittiya rule, but knowingly to
make a false claim to a superior human state is one of the most heinous lies a
bhikkhu can tell, so here it receives its own rule and the heaviest possible
penalty."

Comment: Better to use a term like "rules of defeat" for the parajika rules than "deadly sins".

Comment: The passage quoted is more opinion than  a Sutta. Therefore it should be set aside. It can discourage one to give up on the goal even before starting. Further the authenticity of the Anagathavamsa Sutta is challenged by some scholars and is considered as a later addition.

Comment: It's not an opinion. It's mentioned as the word of the Buddha and it hasn't been rejected by the Buddhist councils. Whether you like to believe it or not is a personal matter.

All Parajikas are bad karmas and they kill one's monk status. So the term fits.

Comment: Can the section quoted in the question be traced to a Sutta? Here's one of many links claiming that the Anagathavamsa Sutta is post canonical.http://www.budsas.org/ebud/metteya/arimet00.htm.

Comment: However this is not to say that the Maitri Buddha is not mentioned or relevant to Dhamma. Just that when citing sources we need to ensure the authenticity of the source. That's all.

Comment: A text being post canonical or not being able to trace to a canonical Sutta does not mean it is inauthentic. If the teaching is inline with the Dhamma and if it is not rejected by the councils, it's pretty safe to accept.

Comment: That is true Sanka.  There are a lot of Sravaka Dhamma in line with the Dhamma. However they are not 'what the Buddha said...' as posted above.

Comment: No, what I meant was you can't make the assumption that every thing the Buddha preached during the 45 years was included in the Tipitaka at the time it was written down